# Ошибка доступа к ветке реестра (создание параметра)

Tags: c#, реестр

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, почему не создается параметр в реестре (только на моем компьютере).
Создаю параметр из программы на C# (запуск хоть под админом, хоть без):

```
Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_SCRIPT",
                                  RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
```

Получаю Exception:

> Невозможно создать статический подпараметр для временного родительского параметра.
>
> в Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)
>
> в Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKeyInternal(String subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck, Object registrySecurityObj, RegistryOptions registryOptions)
>
> в Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKey(String subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck)

Создаю параметр `FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_SCRIPT` вручную в `regedit` - появляется ошибка:

> [Window Title]
>
> Ошибка при создании раздела
>
> [Content]
>
> Не удается создать раздел. Ошибка при записи в реестр.

Необходимые права доступа у `FeatureControl` есть, унаследованы от родительского раздела `Main`, в котором отлично создаются параметры.
И что это за `временный родительский параметр`?

Comment: *И что это за временный родительский параметр?* [Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryoptions): You can create a registry key that is available only in memory and that will not be persisted when the computer is restarted.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло